# How to properly set up ASP.NET web.config to show application specific, safe and user friendly asp.net error messages in edge cases

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, custom-error-handling

In our asp.net web page (.net 4.7.2) we use custom exception rendering logic which creates specific error pages for the user in global.asax.cs via:

```
Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This works fine. However there are some asp.net errors which never hit the `Application_Error`-event.
For those errors, we set explicitly an error page in the web.config via the `customErrors`-element. This looks like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/CustomErrors/FatalError.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"  />
```

**The Problem**
The above works fine in most of the cases. However, there are some few asp.net errors, which are not handled by the `Application_Error` event and also bring the FatalError.aspx to throw an exception, even if there is no asp-code within. A good example of such an error is, when you type the following [reserved address](https://www.bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/) into your browser:

```
https://[yourWebsite]/com1
```

This blows the .aspx- based default error page with the following error message (Http-Status-Code 500):

> ***An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for
> the first exception. The request has been terminated.***

Even setting an aspx-file which has absolutely no asp-code within, leads to this error. The same happens also, if the `defaultRedirect`-attribute is configured to a resource which not exists! It also doesn't make any difference, if there are explict `error`-elements defined under the `customErrors`-element, which define the redirect-resource based on an explicit http statusCode.

When setting the `redirectMode` of the `customErrors`-element to `ResponseRedirect`, the aspx-based default error handler works fine.
However, this is not option, since our client don’t want to see the redirect.

As a workaround, we can try to use a static html file. However, in this case, asp.net sends the response without the correct content-type back to the browser and the HTML-page is rendered as text.
There are lot of posts throughout the internet which state this an error. However, the proposed solution is always either, to use an .aspx-file, or to use the  `Application_Error` event in global.asax.cs to set the content-type manually in code. However, both variants are not possible in this very situation as described above (every aspx-file blows and `Application_Error` is never called).

**Question**
How can we configure a reliable error handling, which never shows any asp.net specific error-information but an application specific one, even with such edge cases as described in this post.
Please note, the question is not about how to circumvent the error with the reserved resource names. This is only an example and there are probably many more other circumstances, where asp.net errors occur, which never reach the `Application_Error` event and bring aspx-based error files down. The goal is really to have a mechanism for rendering application branded error message instead of asp.net error messages, which works fully reliable.

Also as a side node, we use also the httpErrors-element in the webServer-section to change errors which stem not from asp.net but from IIS itself. However, we have not observed any dependency to the problem described above, hence, I have not mentioned that in the main text.

Comment: you could use iis URL rewrite custom response it will work with every browser.also try to set "show friendly HTTP error message" in internet explorer setting [image](https://i.imgur.com/TqTDOQL.png)

Comment: @Jalpa Pnachal: Hi, may you elaborate, how the rewrite could help?

Answer (score 1):

The errors are not pass from `Application_Error` pass from IIS. You can configure this errors on `web.config` on this session.

Here is an example to hand the not found page, witch means most of the errors that not go through `Application_Error`.

403 error is for Forbidder errors.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />      
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />        
     </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

How I use the `Application_Error` on `global.asax`

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // log the last error
    Exception LastOneError = Server.GetLastError();

    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    if (!cTheFile.EndsWith("PageNotFound.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // check for this above -> fPageNotExist
        // reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032497/159270
        if(fPageNotExist)
            Response.Redirect("~/PageNotFound.aspx");
        else
            Server.Transfer("~/PageNotFound.aspx");
    }
}
```

and as you write also use

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
```

The **COM1-9, LPT1-9, AUX, PRT, NUL, CON** files that are [pseudofiles](https://www.bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/) can be avoided using this option on `web.config` - its for IIS

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"   ....other settings.... />

   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

by setting this option you get this files again under asp.net - but **I will not recommented** to do so, because this requests are not come from regular use of your system, and may not be [not be protected well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14995282/159270) if you put it on true.

### web forms and viewStateKey

For `web forms`, one more point that I check for errors is on `viewStateKey` post value - for more details you can read this q/a:

[CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed and Validation of viewstate MAC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821243/cryptographicexception-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-and-validation/2551810#2551810)

Comment: Hi, thanks. This is almost exactly, how we built our configuration (see also the last section of my post). This works in 99.9%, but there are some strange edge cases, as described in my post, which are not handled by IIS but asp.net but blow the whole exception handling. Please check it in one of your (probably MVC-) solutions. Call "http[s]://[yourWebsite]/com1". This will blow your  "error.aspx" and will not call "Application_Error". The error stems not from IIS (you will see, if you get it), hence the "httpErrors"-section will not help. Its this edge cases I'm interested in to resolve.

Comment: As a side note, one can use relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" in sytem.web. However I'm interested in making the error handling more robust and not to supress this very error, since there are probably more such cases out there and its impossible to find and suppress them all. Besides, its not really clear what does relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping from a security standpoint of view.

Comment: @HCL I have update my answer with the solution for this specific pseudofiles - any other specific example ?

Comment: Hi your change is exactly what I described in my second comment. I would not enable this for security reasons. Additionally, as I stated in my post, I'm not interested in disabling this very error but to get an exception visualization which is absolutely waterproof. And for doing so, this reserved addresses are perfectly to test. Currently, I'm a bit further and will post soon another question, which may dig more in the right direction. But thanks for your post anyway. I think its already really sophisticated, since error handling in asp.net seems to me pretty difficult to get right.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66763502/how-to-prevent-mvc5-setting-the-ftryskipcustomerrors-flag-to-true-automatically

Comment: @HCL error handling for regular users is not that sophisticated as you say - if they follow your path - the difficult is to handle the attackers -

Comment: We went to great lengths to hide information about the server from the hacker (removing any treacherous headers etcetera). For the very same reason, we require that never ever a specific asp.net or IIS error is shown to the user (attacker). In principle, this is easy. Use existingResponse="Replace". However, on the other hand, we have the goal to show user friendly messages, including also a support code, which helps identify errors in the logs. And there begins the hazzle. You can have fulfilled one goal or the other. However, to get both, seems quite a struggle.

Answer (score -2):

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode=”On” redirectMode=”ResponseRewrite”>
<error statusCode=”500″ redirect=”~/errorpages/500.aspx” />
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Welcome, Juan. @HCL included the `<customErrors />` option in their original post—but then explained why it doesn't fully satisfy their needs. This answer doesn't address the core concerns animating this question.